# Combine single and multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and I want to match both arrays.If the value from `array 1` is not present in `array 2` then I would like to put `0` for that element.

Array 1

```
$weeksArr = array("p1","p2","p3","p4");
```

Array 2

```
$dailyArr = array(
    "0"=>array("p1","123"),
    "1"=>array("p2","125"),
    "2"=>array("p4","126")
);
```

After joining I would like to the final array to be

```
$finalArr = array(
    "0"=>array("p1","123"),
    "1"=>array("p2","125"),
    "2"=>array("p3","0"),
    "3"=>array("p4","126")
);
```

So I would like to insert `p3` inside final array.

Any hint/suggestion is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: php's array functions like `array_intersect` are very useful for that kind of things

Comment: If you please point me out about the reason of down vote then I will correct that thing next time for sure :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks currently I am going through the function examples.

Comment: I think it's related to the fact that you did not know of the php array functions. some research there along with how this did not let you solve the problem might have prevented that downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the shortest way to get there, but you could get all the p's first then compare to the weeks.

After getting the differences, loop that an assign, then finally sort them again.

```
$weeksArr = array("p1","p2","p3","p4");
$dailyArr = array("0"=>array("p1","123"),"1"=>array("p2","125"),"2"=>array("p4","126"));
$finalArr = $dailyArr;

$temp = array_map(function($piece){ return $piece[0]; }, $finalArr); // get all p's
$diff = array_diff($weeksArr, $temp); // get the missing p
foreach($diff as $w) { 
    $finalArr[] = array($w, 0); // assign missing p
}
usort($finalArr, function($a, $b){ // you do not need this is you do not care about the order
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]); // if you need to order them, p1, p2, p3, p4, then i guess you need to sort
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: this is complicated... you do not need to do all that diff checking, just assign the final array while iterating through the first.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yeah your solution if fine too much straightforward

Comment: @Ghost yeah, probably yours would react better if arrays would not be formatted exactly like I expect them to be

Answer (score 2):

Was a bit trickier then I thought, but this simple nested foreach loop will make it:

```
$weeksArr = array("p1","p2","p3","p4");
$dailyArr = array("0"=>array("p1","123"),"1"=>array("p2","125"),"2"=>array("p4","126"));

foreach ($weeksArr as $i => $value) {
  foreach ($dailyArr as $a) {
    if ($a[0] == $value) $finalArray[$i] = array($a[0],$a[1]);
  }
  if (!isset($finalArray[$i])) $finalArray[$i] = array($value,0);
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sort $weeksArr
2. sort $dailyArr such that $dailyArr[i][0] <= $dailyArr[i+1][0]
3. initialize two variables i,j with 0 and $finalArray with an empty array

DO

4.a if $weeksArr[i] equals $dailyArr[j][0], add $dailyArr[j] to $finalArr and increment i and j

4.b if $weeksArr[i] < $dailyArr[j][0], add a new entry to $finalArr for $weekArr[i] and increment i

5. cancel loop if i or j gets out of bounds

LOOP

6. if i is smaller than the length of $weekArr, then add the remaining entries to $finalArr